# Delphi function to convert Result of WrapText to TStringList

Tags: delphi

I use this function to insert carriage returns on a string so it is nicely formatted for emailing:

```
  m := WrapText(m, #13#10, ['.',' ',#9,'-'], 60);
```

The problem is my email client has a 1023 character limit when processing strings.  So if the original length of **m** is greater than 1023, it gets truncated (Note: the email client probably has events to handle this situation, but I think an easier approach is to just feed it strings less than the limit).

I am looking for a "**WrapTextToStringList**" function like this:

```
var
  mStringList: TStringList;
begin
  mStringList := WrapTextToStringList(m, #13#10, ['.',' ',#9,'-'], 60);
```

So say I passed this a 220 character body of an email message.  The results would be a string list with approximately 4 entries.

I think this just boils down to creating a function which parses a string at **#13#10** into a string list.

Anyone got one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TStringList` already has a built-in method to parse a string at `#13#10` into a string list.

```
MyStringList := TStringList.Create;
MyStringList.Text := MyString;
```

This will populate the list by parsing the string and creating a new entry in the list whenever it finds a return.